# Plot to create a Northern Confederation of States in America about 1804

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, independence, us-constitution

I read in "Asimov's book of facts" that there was a (failed) plot to create such Confederation, that should include New York city, but I couldn't find any other reference. Asimov's book doesn't give names of involved politicians.

Can any of you give more information?

Comment: Please, can you explain the vote to close this question? Is it a duplicate? Is it off topic? Asimov's book is not a proper history source, but it's a well known and respected writer, not a fringe or conspirative author.

Comment: [Yankee Confederates](http://ditext.com/dilorenzo/yankee.html)

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace That's perfect. If you transcribe your comment to an aswer I'd be glad to accept it.

Comment: There was the [Burr Conspiracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burr_conspiracy) but that was 1805-06 and in the SW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yankee Confederates](http://ditext.com/dilorenzo/yankee.html) is a probable answer based on the 1804 date.

Comment: Got any other links for this? That one has a lot of good info, but its trying so hard to use this incident to draw parallels to the Civil War that I worry about that agenda tainting its depiction.

Comment: I'll google fu later - but frankly if you search for secession 1804 you'll find some.  Search for the terms in the referenced document and you'll find more.

Comment: @T.E.D. The agenda becomes pretty clear if you lookup the author: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_DiLorenzo)[Thomas DiLorenzo
]. To be sure, there is a lot of interesting factual information there but  he *is* trying far too hard to justify the Confederate secession. I would have been perfectly fine with that (what's wrong with some scholarly debate?) but for the infinite contumely of his remarks on the 3/5 clause:

Comment: "What the Federalists wanted, and what their assaults upon the three-fifths clause were designed to gain, was not the abolition of slavery but the abolition of Negro representation."  Mr. DiLorenzo apparently would have us believe that the slaves were represented in some meaningful sense by their owners!

Comment: @T.E.D. I'm going to accept Mark's answer, and I will post another answer with some quotes from wikipedia that contain some additional and  "agenda-free" unbiased information, or I hope so.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the tips that @MarkC.Wallace gave me, and [through wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Secession_in_the_United_States&section=8#New_England_Federalists_and_the_Hartford_Convention), I've found some facts about [Timothy Pickering (1745-1829)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothy_Pickering), a politician from Massachusetts, that I find useful on this topic:

> Timothy Pickering of Massachusetts and a few Federalists envisioned creating a separate New England confederation, possibly combining with lower Canada to form a new pro-British nation. Historian Richard Buell, Jr., characterizes these separatist musings:
>
> > Most participants in the explorations—it can hardly be called a plot since it never took concrete form—focused on the domestic obstacles to consummating their fantasy. These included lack of popular support for such a scheme in the region. ... The secessionist movement of 1804 was more of a confession of despair about the future than a realistic proposal for action.

This last paragraph is from the book ["America on the Brink: How the Political Struggle Over the War of 1812 Almost Destroyed the Young Republic"](https://books.google.es/books?id=iKnPCgAAQBAJ) by Richard Buel Jr.